# How to send dynamic parameter values in JDBC request of Jmeter

Tags: sql, jmeter

**Requirement:**
1) I need to fetch values from an external dynamic file (Number of values may differ at each run)
2) Use all those values in the JDBC Request to fetch data from DB using JMeter

**Problem:**
1) I am able to fetch values from external file using bean shell
2) But i am facing issues in sending those values to JDBC Request as it would need me to provide exact number of Parameter Types along with Parameter values and that too dynamically(as the number of values from external file differs)

**DB Query:**
 select a.acc_no,an.first_name,an.last_name,b.bi_no,b.due
  from accou a, bill_t b, NAME_T an
  where a.acc_no in(?) and a.poid=b.acc_obj and a.poid=an.obj;

[image: JDBC Sampler used]

If the number of parameter values is only one, we get the correct response.
But if the number of parameter values are more than one(in this case, i have provided four values), we are getting error as 'number of arguments (4) and number of types (1) are not equal'.

I will not be able to know how many parameter types i need to add to JDBC Request dynamically. If the number of Parameter Values and Parameter Types were constant, adding the same number of Parameter Types and corresponding values would have brought us the desired result.

[image: JDBC Sampler with four parameter values]
[image: Response of JDBC Sampler with four values]

So how can we send dynamically multiple parameter values to jdbc request in Jmeter?

Comment: hi any solution